# ListBoxItem height not getting updated

Tags: wpf, listbox, height, listboxitem, invalidation

I have a listbox inside another list box, in inner list box listboxitems height may grow or shrink. My problem is that when the inner items shrink the outer list box doesn't re-render its height. Thus - stays with the previous height before the inner list shrinked.

I have tried so many things here, among Invalidate of all types, selection and de-selection of the list box item that should be updated and more - nothing helps....

Can anyone pls help me with this?

Thanx,
Gili

Comment: Could you post some code?  Is the inner listboxes height set to Auto?  I am assuming you want the inner listboxes items to grow/shrink, changing it's height, thus in turn changing the outer box's height also.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the heck of it I did the following:

```
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="283" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ListBox Margin="0,0,-274,0">
            <ListBoxItem Content="Text"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Text"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Text"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Text"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Text"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Text"/>
        </ListBox>
        <ListBox Margin="0,0,-274,0">
            <ListBoxItem Content="Text"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Text"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Text"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Text"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Text"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Text"/>
        </ListBox>
        <ListBox Margin="0,0,-274,0">
            <ListBoxItem Content="Text"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Text"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Text"/>
        </ListBox>
        <ListBox Margin="0,0,-274,0">
            <ListBoxItem Content="Text"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Text"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Text"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Text"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Text"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Text"/>
        </ListBox>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Now I realize the items in the list boxes are not created at run-time, however I created a little button with click handler which adds items to one of the middle listboxes, and everything resizes appropriately.

If you post your code, we can take a look and see what is out of whack.

Answer (score 0):

Take this for example:

```
    <ListBox VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="500">
        <ListBox x:Name="Item1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="300" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="5">
            <ListBox.Items>
                <RichTextBox VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="300" SizeChanged="OnInnserItemSizeChanged"/>
                <RichTextBox VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="300"/>
                <RichTextBox VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="300"/>
            </ListBox.Items>
        </ListBox>
        <ListBox x:Name="Item2" BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="5" Width="300" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <ListBox.Items>
                <RichTextBox VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="300"/>
                <RichTextBox VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="300"/>
                <RichTextBox VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="300"/>
            </ListBox.Items>
        </ListBox>            
    </ListBox>
```

Now, when i run it and click 'Enter'/'Return' in the one of the RichTextBoxes, the outer listbox item stretches to match the new size - but when i delete the newly added row it doesn't resize back to its original size...

Thanx,
Gili

Comment: Gili - I recommend you place your updated question material back into your original question as an edit. Answers on Stack Overflow are to be used to supplying answers to the original question and nothing more.